# Catch hidden fields in form change event using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form like below

```
<form:form id="depositDetailsFormTab" method="post" action="${depositDetailsFormContactMe}"  modelAttribute="DepositDetails">
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
    <span class="pull-right manfields"><span class="red-star">*</span>Mandatory Fields</span>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <label class="labelname">Amount In</label> <input
                class="form-control" id="amountin" type="text" name="amountIn">
        </div>
    </div>      
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <label class="labelname">Category</label> 
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-select custom-drop-down"> 
                <input type="hidden" class="btn-select-input" id="" name="category" value=""> 
                <span class="btn-select-value">Select an Item</span> 
                <span class="btn-select-arrow glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                    <ul class="category" id="category" style="display: none;">
                        <li>DHFL Promoter</li>
                        <li>Director</li>
                        <li>Relative of Director</li>
                        <li>Shareholder</li>
                        <li>Public</li>
                    </ul>
            </a>
        </div>          
    </div>
    <div class="formbtn">       
        <button class=" btn secondary-btn" type="button" id="btn_depositdetails_submit">Save &amp; Continue</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form:form>
```

In this form I have a hidden field which catches the selected list item. Designers used ul li instead of select dropdown.

Here I am trying to catch the form change event using jquery like below

```
$("#depositDetailsFormTab :input").change(function() {
   alert("changed");
});
```

It is firing when first input box changed but not alerting when I change the list item in dropdown. Actually I am updating the hidden field when list item changes.

So, how to include hidden fields in form change event?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that changing a value for an hidden field doesn't automatically fire "onchange" event. So I would suggest to try to fire it manually. For example:

```
$("#hiddenFieldId").val("NewVal").change();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call .trigger('change') on your field when you set it (after selecting your li)